# eclipse not showing the file i created earlier

Tags: eclipse, cucumber

when i'm trying to open a project which already did in eclipse, now  it showing blank screen while opening . how to overcome this issue[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZpVA.png)

I'm trying to open the project in a eclipse which i already did,but now it's showing blank screen

Answer (score 0):

That's not a blank screen, it's one where you've maximized the Error Log view by double clicking on its tab. Double-click it again, or Reset the Perspective from the Window menu in the menu bar.